# "C'est la catastrophe" vs "C'est une catastrophe"?

Tags: grammaire, sens, traduction, vocabulaire, formulation-idiomatique

I translated this and they meant the same thing.

Why does *la* and *une* mean the same thing here?

Comment: Whoever voted to close because you can look it up in a dictionary, this is wrong. This is really a question about the mismatch of the use of the definite article in English and French. In particular, the question seems to be: why does Google Translate translate them both as "this is *a* disaster/catastrophe", instead of *la catastrophe* becoming "*the* disaster", the way you might naïvely expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the use of the definite article emphasizes the size of the catastrophe. When I say *c'est une catastrophe* I could easily use "disaster" in English. But when I say *C'est la catastrophe* it sounds as if I were using a superlative, as if I was meaning it is the ultimate catastrophe, the worst thing that could happen to me (and in English I would rather not use "disaster" but "catastrophe") and would definitely add an adjective to intensify the depth of the *catastrophe*: "it's a real catastrophe".

Answer (score -1):

The two articles do not mean the same thing. The « normal » article is  « une ». « La  » is used by people  who look at the noun  « catastrophe » in a particular way which is highly idiomatic and not necessarily accepted by the majority of the  educated speakers. This is just as in the case of the following example, of which occurrences can be  heard in regional speech of the less educated sort.

> - Le dimache il met une chemise(une cravate, un costume, un chapeau, etc.).
> - Le dimache il met la chemise (la cravate, le costume, le chapeau, etc.). (*This particular set of usages is not accepted by most educated speakers;
>   note that the use of « la » does not  imply that the man possesses only one shirt, he usually has several.*)

> ([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_Coupe_immonde/AcFXDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22c%27est+la+d%C3%A9bacle%22&pg=PT53&printsec=frontcoverhttps://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_Coupe_immonde/AcFXDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22c%27est+la+d%C3%A9bacle%22&pg=PT53&printsec=frontcover)) Et l'autre, d'une voix plus grave, répétait : – C'est la débâcle ! C'est la débâcle ! Et ceci dans une chaîne sans fin.